# What are these little diamonds on my tape measure?

Tags: measurement

Not a very important question, but I'm wondering what the little diamonds are on my tape measure. It's a Stanley Fatmax from the UK © 2011. The first one is at ~488 mm (~19.2 inch), and then every ~488 mm after that along the tape, but they don't align with any regular measurement in can fathom.

[image]

Comment: See https://www.simplemost.com/heres-diamonds-measuring-tape/ for example

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/55152/18078

Answer (score 4):

It is an alternative framing spacing, used for studs, joists and rafters. It is an "identifier" for a stud layout much like the 16" center layout where you will get an even amount of spaces over an 8 ft. piece of material, or for that matter a 16 ft. piece of material as well.

Comment: In other words, instead of 6 studs per 8' span, you get 5 joists for the 8' span.

Comment: Huh... I've heard of studs on 16" & 24" centers, but 19" centers?

Comment: @FreeMan — it varies from place to place, but those are usually drawn by architects that hate carpenters ;)

Comment: I have used those center marks myself. I was building an outbuilding using 2X6 oak salvaged from a barn, and needed to adjust my framing to work with the material I had. It worked out pretty good for my occasion.

Comment: So useless in the UK as we don't have matchstick houses?

Comment: @PaulUszak ,  don't count it out yet, I would think the roof is still done with framing.